# "Táco" is wider than "Taco". How can I fix that?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to load a div with diacritics on top of a div without. The spacing isn't working out like I though. (See the snippet below.) How can I fix this?

```css
div.text {
     width: 75%;
     position: relative;
 }
 div.diacritics {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
      z-index: -1;
      color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="text">String String String String String String String String String String
 <div class="diacritics">
  Stríng Stríng Stríng Stríng Stríng Stríng Stríng Stríng Stríng Stríng</div>
  </div>

<div class="text">Taco Taco Taco Taco Taco Taco Taco Taco Taco Taco
 <div class="diacritics">
  Táco Táco Táco Táco Táco Táco Táco Táco Táco Táco</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue on Mac OS X: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BH9Sw.png

Comment: As a counterpoint, I'm also on OS X yet do see the issue -- I assume it's a difference in installed fonts.   Which suggests that the answer to this question is "Don't try to do that, because the results aren't easily predictable."

Comment: If it matters that `"Táco"` is not always exactly the same width as `"Taco"`, then your layout should be more robust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div.text {
         width: 75%;
         position: relative;
            font-family: monospace;
     }
div.diacritics {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
            font-family: monospace;
          z-index: -1;
          color: red;
     }
```

```html
    <div class="text">String String String String String String String String String String
     <div class="diacritics">
      Stríng Stríng Stríng Stríng Stríng Stríng Stríng Stríng Stríng Stríng</div>
      </div>

    <div class="text">Taco Taco Taco Taco Taco Taco Taco Taco Taco Taco
     <div class="diacritics">
      Táco Táco Táco Táco Táco Táco Táco Táco Táco Táco</div>
      </div>
```

If you are able to make the trade-off, you could always try using a monospace font family.

Comment: I guess this answers the question best even though I'd prefer to not use that font. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to want to look at **[font-kerning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-kerning)**.

> The font-kerning CSS property controls the usage of the kerning
>   information; that is, it controls how letters are spaced. The kerning
>   information is stored in the font, and if the font is well-kerned,
>   this feature allows spacing between characters to be very similar,
>   whatever the characters are.

Check out this pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKPMGM, I set kerning to none and they lined up.

```
div.text {
        width: 75%;
        position: relative;
        font-kerning:none;
    }
    div.diacritics {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        font-kerning:none;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      z-index: -1;
      color: red;
    }
```

A little more info.

> Kerning adjusts the space between individual letter forms, while
>   tracking (letter-spacing) adjusts spacing uniformly over a range of
>   characters. In a well-kerned font, the two-dimensional blank spaces
>   between each pair of characters all have a visually similar area.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work on my mac os x. I wonder why some can reproduce the issue and some can't.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're assigning a font. What font are you wanting to use?