# How can I use the exact width of wrapped text rather than that of the full container?

Tags: html, css

I have some text which is constrained to a particular width, so it wraps. I want to display a border around the **wrapped text**. When I add a border, it wraps the text *plus the unused space around it*. Is there a way to apply the border to *just* the text? Here's an illustration of what I mean: I have drawn a red line where I want the right-hand edge of the element to be:

[image]

#### HTML:

```
  <div>
    Supercalifragilistic expialidocious
  </div>
```

#### CSS:

```
div {
  max-width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9Lw7uuy/1/)

Comment: You can't...that's not the way the line-box model works.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377826/css-width-max-width-on-line-wrap/12377883#12377883

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could work for short text. Combining `attr()` and `pseudo`.

```css
.outer {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;  
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
.inner {      
  display: inline;
  position:relative;
}
.inner:before {
  content: attr(data-text) " ";
  color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;top:0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner" data-text="Supercalifragilistic expialidocious">Supercalifragilistic expialidocious</div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Absolute positioning inside inline elements & **limitations** of the above example.

> [From CSS2.1 specs 10.1.4](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details): if an element is absolute positioned inside a inline element spanning multiple lines, its containing block is undefined.

By defining the top and left positions,we get the browsers to align the `pseudo` to the corresponding top and left edges of the **first box created by its 'ancestor'.** By definition, pseudo is a virtual child of any selected element and an `absolute` looks for a nearest positioned ancestor. Though the inline rule points to no containing block, the position rule works in favour for the top/left sides.

We then allow the pseudo to take the height as computed from its content/intrinsic dimension. Since `attr()` pulls the same content, it more or less overlaps well on the text in its ancestor. ([when without any font inconsistencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37450633/5496966)).

**But do note, while it may work for single line text its dependent on the white-space/wrap/font and its not consistent across browsers when dealing with multi-line inline elements.**

Here is what I mean.

```css
.outer {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-family: monospace;
}
.inner {
  color: black;
  position: relative;
}
.inner:after {
  content: attr(data-text) " ";  
  position: absolute;
  left:-1px;top:-1px;right:-1px; /* compensating for the border */
  pointer-events: none;
  color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer"><span class="inner" data-text="single line inline">single line inline</span></div><div class="outer"><span class="inner" data-text="This is a multi-line inline element which may not hold an absolute positioned pseudo element. Fails in Chrome.">This is a multi-line inline element which may not hold an absolute positioned pseudo element. Fails in Chrome.</span></div>
```

Comment: Don't know why you were downvoted. This looks like it could work, although it would be good if you could explain what's happening here. I guess the `::before` pseudo-element takes the width of the `.inner` div by default?

Comment: Cos its absolute positioned. It doesn't wrap like a normal inline element would. Its fills the parent instead. And cos the parent is an inline element setting border the way you need would be easy.